# OnLongClickListener and Data Binding - void cannot be converted to boolean (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, data-binding, onlongclicklistener

How can I integrate a longclick listener with data binding?
It needs a boolean return.
But apparently my method cannot return a value (void)

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = LayoutTrainBaseItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);


        binding.Button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> myFunction());

        binding.Button.setOnLongClickListener(view1 -> myFunction());
```

Thank you very much for a tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[View.OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener) is a SAM-interface whose abstract method returns `boolean` (unlike [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener), where the return type is `void`).

If `myFunction()` returned `boolean`, the line `binding.Button.setOnLongClickListener(view1 -> myFunction());` would work.

For example, the following will compile in your case:

```
binding.Button.setOnLongClickListener(view1 -> {
    myFunction();
    return true;
});
```

As for the return value, the docs say:

> true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

Please consider it for your logic

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = LayoutTrainBaseItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    
        binding.Button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> myFunction());
        
        binding.Button.setOnLongClickListener(view1 -> {
            myFunction();
            return true; // Return true to consume the long click event
        });
    
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```